# how to save base64 image decode to public folder in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-7

I get an image with format String base64 and i want to decode that string to be an image and save it to public folder in laravel.

This is my controller:

```
//decode string base64 image to image 
$image = base64_decode($request->input('ttd'));
//create image name
$photo_name = time().'.png';
$destinationPath = public_path('/uploads');
//save image to folder
$image->move($destinationPath, $photo_name);
$img_url = asset('/uploads'.$photo_name);


$data = new Transaction();
$data->transaction_id = $request->input('fa_transaction_id');
$data->user_id = $request->input('userid');
$data->photo_name = $photo_name;
$data->photo_url = $img_url;
$data->save();
```

when i'm trying echo $image, i got the decode value, and also for $photo_name i got the value too, but when the function running i got this error

```
Call to a member function move() on string
```

how to fix this error?

Comment: You don’t have any kind of “file” object here that would have a `move` method, you have a string, no more, no less. So you need to write that string into a file yourself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
//Controller

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

//Inside method

    $image = $request->image;  // your base64 encoded
    $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $image);
    $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
    $imageName = str_random(10) . '.png';

    Storage::disk('local')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

Also, make sure that your `local` disk is configured like that in `/config/filesystems.php`

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
    ]
```

With that, file will be saved in `/storage/app/public` directory.

Don't forget to write `php artisan storage:link` to make files from that directory available in `/public` directory, so users will can retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Saving image in database not a recommanded way to store image in db, reason is speed increase of memory, The correct way is just save the link to it. 
Anyway, you can save your image in `base64` with these line of code. 
Get the correct image from path in your server not from link in the `$path`.

```
<?php
    // Base 64 transform image
    $path = __DIR__ .'/myfolder/myimage.png';
    $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($path);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    echo $base64;
```